# column header center align , but want the cell right align

Tags: html, css

I want the cell align center , but keep text right align. for detail please run the code.

```css
table{border:solid ; width:100%}

th{text-align:center}
td{text-align:center}
```

```html
<div>now my table show like this</div>
<table>  
<tr><th>hello</th><th>world</th><th>jasper</th></tr>
<tr><td>123</td><td>456</td><td>789</td></tr>  
<tr><td>1231</td><td>4561</td><td>7891</td></tr>  
<tr><td>12312</td><td>45612</td><td>78912</td></tr>  

</table>
<br>
<div>but i want to like this</div>
<table>  
<tr><th>hello</th><th>world</th><th>jasper</th></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;123</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;456</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;789</td></tr>  
<tr><td>&nbsp;1231</td><td>&nbsp;4561</td><td>&nbsp;7891</td></tr>  
<tr><td>12312</td><td>45612</td><td>78912</td></tr>  

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

i solve it with add more `th` and `td` but it work Correctly

[image: table]

code

```css
table{border:solid ; width:100%}

th{text-align:center}
td{text-align:right}
#td{
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>now my table show like this</div>
<table>  
<tr><th>&nbsp</th><th id="td">hello</th><th>&nbsp</th><th id="td">world</th><th>&nbsp</th><th id="td">jasper</th><th>&nbsp</th></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp</td><td id="td">123</td><td>&nbsp</td><td id="td">456</td><td>&nbsp</td><td id="td">789</td><td>&nbsp</td></tr>  
<tr><td>&nbsp</td><td id="td">1231</td><td>&nbsp</td><td id="td">4561</td><td>&nbsp</td><td id="td">7891</td><td>&nbsp</td></tr> 
<tr><td>&nbsp</td><td id="td">12312</td><td>&nbsp</td><td id="td">45612</td><td>&nbsp</td><td id="td">78912</td><td>&nbsp</td></tr>
```

http://liveweave.com/6EFpKY

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add a div inside th th and td elements and give them a fixed length.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <div>hello</div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div>world</div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div>jasper</div>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>123</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>456</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>789</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>1231</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>4561</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>7891</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>12312</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>45612</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>78912</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table {
    border:solid;
    width:100%
}
td div {
    width:40px;
    text-align:right;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
th div {
    width:40px;
    text-align:right;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Try it out:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/hdgjnuab/1/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS and HTML table code with below one.

**CSS:**

```
table{border:solid ; width:100%}
th{text-align:center}
td{direction:rtl;}
.title {margin-right:46%;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>  
<tr><th>hello</th><th>world</th><th>jasper</th></tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="title">123</span></td>
<td><span class="title">456</span></td><td><span class="title">789</span></td></tr>  
<tr><td><span class="title">1231</span></td><td><span class="title">4561</span></td><td><span class="title">7891</span></td></tr>  
<tr><td><span class="title">12312</span></td><td><span class="title">45612</span></td><td><span class="title">78912</span></td></tr>  

</table>
```

**Output:**
[image]

No need to define fix width of table cells.